# Volume of voice (loud/quiet/whisper) when reading Quran from mus'haf?

Tags: quran, reading-quran

When I read the Quran from a mus'haf, I read it with a low whisper with my tongue slightly moving. Is this the correct voice volume and way to read Quran from a mus'haf? If not, then what is the correct way?

I am a woman who reads the Quran after Fajr prayer and/or after Dhuhr Prayer. I read the Quran in my room. I read the Quran to gain rewards from Allah.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no correct way to recite the qur'an.
For qualifying a correct manner for the recitation you need to be more specific:
Are you male or female is there an audience or not? If so what kind of audience (gender, belief etc.)? What is your intention when you recite? Are you listening to your recitation or trying to apply the rules of tajweed or just reading and maybe looking in a Tafseer or translation to understand what you read/recite...

In most of the above cases it is better to recite in a louder voice so that you may hear and listen to your own words. While in some cases it might not be good or even disliked. But in general it is recommended (some scholars may consider it as rather essential) to move the lips while reciting/reading the qur'an.